# Getting an NSDictionary by filtering another NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nspredicate, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Hope someone could help me with that :

I'm using a `NSDictionary` to fill a `UITableView`.
Its model is like `[key:userID => value:userName]`.
The tableView is only filled with userName but when clicked, it has to send the userID related.
The problem comes when I want to filter the `UITable`. I only found the way to filter a Dictionary by transforming it into `NSArray` (using Predicate) but it make me loose the relation between userNames and userIDs.

A solution would be to filter the initial `NSDictionary` to get a filtered `NSDictionary` (with still the relational key/value), but I don't know how to do that. I only found solutions to get Arrays.

How could I do that, or is there a better solution to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much better solution, François.
Create, from your `NSDictionary` (I will call it here `myDictionary`), an `NSArray` like this (declare it in your interface file):

```
NSArray *arrayForTableView;
```

Then, just after you load your NSDictionary, do the following:

```
arrayForTableView = [myDictionary allKeys]; // so you will have an array of all UserID's
```

Now, in your `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you can do it like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [myDictionary objectForKey:[arraForTableView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

And then, when you will want to pass the userID when the user selects the cell, in your `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you just do it this way:

```
id userIDSelected = [arraForTableView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Then, when you want to filter the array according to the search, you can simply recreate your `arrayForTableView`, by "scanning" your NSDictionary this way:

```
NSString *typedString;
NSMutableArray *arrayFiltered = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < [[myDictionary allKeys] count]; i++)
{
    if ([[myDictionary objectForKey:[[myDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:i]] rangeOfString:typedString].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        [arrayFiltered addObject:[[myDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}

arrayForTableView = arrayFiltered;
```

This way, you won't even need to change your UITableView dataSource and delegate methods.

Comment: All right, I got your point. I took the problem from the wrong side and I was disturb by the non-problem of identical values. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad I helped. Please vote up also if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to do that yet, but I will :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do following to get value(userID) for selected key(userName) :

```
//iterate through whole dictionary
for(id key in yourNSDictionary)
{
   // if key is the userName clicked
   if([key isEqualToString:selectedUserName])
   {
       //userID for clicked userName
       int userID = [yourNSDictionary objectForKey:@selectedUserName];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're using an NSDictionary to populate an UITableView and this UITableView is only filled with the username which you get by doing

```
[dictionary objectForKey@"userID"];
```

a NSDictionary has two functions allkeys and allValues

```
NSArray* allUserID = [dictionary allKeys];
NSArray* allUserNames = [dictionary allValues];
```

this is a parallel arrays so that the index of one array, runs parallel with it's associated array.

Each cell of the table cell could also be a custom class that holds a reference to it's own id and username, this will allow you to only pass the cell and have it's data.

you can read about those functions in the NSDictionary documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I agree that the two allKey and allValues are parallel, but when I was using a predicate on the allValues (userName) array, I had a filtered name array, but no more related IDs. Now I solved my problem but the custom class is a good idea too. I'll probably keep that in mind for further use ;)

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend creating an NSArray or NSMutableArray with NSDictionary values - UITableViews are meant to be driven by arrays, where the array index matches the row number. Then you can easily create a custom filter for the array of dictionaries which take into account your data structure. Your code might include parts of this sample code:

```
NSString *idKey = @"userId";
NSString *nameKey = @"userName";
NSArray *arr = @[
        @{
                idKey : @(24),
                nameKey : @"Oil Can Henry"
        },
        @{
                idKey : @(32),
                nameKey : @"Doctor Eggman"
        },
        @{
                idKey : @(523),
                nameKey : @"Sparticus"
        },
];
NSString *searchTerm = @"Spar";
NSArray *newArray = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject[nameKey] hasPrefix:searchTerm];
}]];
```

Advantages:

- a single data structure to represent all your data
- inherent, deterministic ordering
- support for NSPredicate filtering